# IE bug push content down and right - how to solve it?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

The layout gets broken in IE6 like in a picture:[image]

[**The site code**](http://www.automatydrzwiowe.pl/trunk/index.php?event=product&parent_id=30&menu_id=2)

Does anybody knows how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: In Poland, IE use is _very_ low, I don't think you'll need to bother with supporting IE6, ever. http://ranking.pl/

Comment: I know but my client uses it :(

Comment: @True North Creative view-source:http://www.automatydrzwiowe.pl/trunk/index.php?event=product&parent_id=131&menu_id=2

Answer (score 0):

Well, taking a quick peek at your code:

```
.clear {
clear: both;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
visibility: hidden;
width: 0;
height: 0;
}
```

IE6 doesn't support height: 0 - you can play with line-height though

The other alignment issues, I would play with putting ie6 specific styles in there and try and break/fix it.

You do you this with adding an underscore in your css, like:

```
height: 100px; /* all browsers see thing */
_height: 200px; /* only ie6 sees this */
```

It's a little hacky, but will help you figure out where you need to have ie6-specific styles.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebug-lite to help you solve this.  It works in any browser - you just add a javascript link to  in your html and you get a firebug-like interface with which to view your elements (and their margins and padding).  It helped me with a layout problem on IE6 yesterday.